x64 REX prefix for 16bit registers
I am confused about the REX prefix:

The docs say the REX is defined by:

REX Bits:
|7|6|5|4|3|2|1|0|
|0|1|0|0|W|R|X|B|
W bit = Operand size 1==64-bits, 0 == legacy, depends on opcode.
R bit = Extends the ModR/M reg field to 4 bits. 0 selects rax-rsi, 1 selects r8-r15
X bit = extends SIB 'index' field, same as R but for the SIB byte (memory operand)
B bit = extends the ModR/M r/m or 'base' field or the SIB field.  


I understand legacy means 32bit;
I understand any REX byte starts with 0100;

But:
$ echo 'mov %al, %al' | as -al -o /dev/null - | tail -1
   1 0000 88C0      mov %al,%al
$ echo 'mov %ax, %ax' | as -al -o /dev/null - | tail -1
   1 0000 6689C0    mov %ax,%ax
$ echo 'mov %eax, %eax' | as -al -o /dev/null - | tail -1
   1 0000 89C0      mov %eax,%eax
$ echo 'mov %rax, %rax' | as -al -o /dev/null - | tail -1
   1 0000 4889C0    mov %rax,%rax


Is that 0x66 a REX prefix on %ax ? Is there another name for that byte?
0x66 is 0110 0110, so it does not match the starts with the 0100 rule to be a REX.
Does it mean I must flip the third bit to set the 16-bit mode registers?


66 is not REX, 66 is prefix to indicate that 16 bit opcode should be used with 32 bit registers, REX here is only in last example 48

66 is osize (operand size change prefix) and 67 is asize (address size change prefix). These both date back to the 386 where every CS had either a clear D bit (16-bit default size, 66/67 will change to 32-bit size) or a set D bit (32-bit default size, 66/67 will change to 16-bit size).

66h is the operand size override prefix.  Basically, in 32- or 64-bit mode, it specifies that the instruction is to operate on 16-bit data and use 16-bit registers.  (In 16-bit mode, it specifies that the instruction operates on 32-bit data.)
So it is a prefix, but it's not a REX prefix.  Indeed, it predates the whole REX prefix system; it has existed since the 386, the first 32-bit x86 CPU, whereas REX is specific to x86-64.
